# char.IsNumber()

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a Windows Form application. I use `char.IsNumber()` to check the key pressed is a number or not:

```
   private void AmBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {
       if(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
           e.Handled=true;
   }
```

MSDN says that `char.IsNumber()` checks a key char is number or not, so if it is a number it returns true. From what I've seen, the result is reversed - it ignores numbers(1,2,3....) instead of characters(A,a,b,c...).

I can solve the problem if I use `!char.IsNumber();` but I can't understand what this method `char.IsNumber()` does. Could someone kindly explain in detail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char.IsNumber()` returns `true` if the character is a number (`'0'`, `'1'`, ... `'9'`).

And `e.Handled = true` says *"this event was already handled, so ignore it"*.

So your code effectively means this:

```
if (e.KeyChar is a number)
    Ignore this event
```

Looking at it this way, you probably see why your code only ignores numbers.

So the solution of using `!char.IsNumber()` is correct, as it basically says *"If the character is **not** a number, ignore this event"*.

Also, note that you probably are looking for [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh), as [`Char.IsNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y.aspx) also recognizes other characters as numbers. `Char.IsDigit` returns `true` only for `'0'` to `'9'`, which is most probably what you want.

Comment: Note that it's not only `'0'` to `'9'`. `IsNumber()` is UNICODE-aware, so it will return `true` for e.g. [Eastern Arabic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) or [Chinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals) numerals.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I was already comparing both methods while you were writing the comment. Good point :)

Answer (score 5):

You're using [Char.IsNumber()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isnumber.aspx) correctly, and it does return `true` if the passed character qualifies as a number.

Your problem lies with the [Handled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled.aspx) property. When you set it to `true`, you're basically telling the framework *I already handled this, you do not have anything else to do with that event*, which prevents the default behavior from being exercised. In other words, characters for which you set `Handled` to `true` are ignored.

That's why you have to invert your condition:

```
if (!Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)) {
    // e.KeyChar is not a number, block it.
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is more likely that because you are marking the event as handled when the character is a number the event is not "bubbling" up to whatever method actually handles it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if(!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
           e.Handled=true;
```